# Inverting op amp design saturates at a fraction of power supply

Tags: operational-amplifier, breadboard, saturation

I have built a simple inverting op amp. I am applying a 1 Vpp sinusoid at 10 Hz to a design with ~4.7x gain. The resistors I am using are 47kOhm and 10 kOhm. The op amp chip is the [LT1222](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1222fc.pdf), and I am applying +/- 15 volts to power it. I also have 0.1uF capacitors running between the power supply and ground. The output sinusoid signal saturates around 4 Vpp, or at +/-2 Vp. From my understanding, the saturation voltage should be close to the supply voltage, and I'm not applying very much gain or a high frequency signal. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 10/3/19 12:43 PM:**
Thank you for the replies so far. I have tried a few things including changing out the chip for a new one and a 741 and they both have about the same saturation voltage. I turned around the backwards capacitor and also added in a 10 uF in parallel to the others. I also replaced the short at the positive terminal with a resistor value of around 8 kOhms.

Here is a better drawing of my setup, a schematic and the actual output signal. The yellow is the amplified signal. There's some high frequency where the clipping is, but I noticed it goes away if I turn down the supply voltages to ~+/-6 V.

[image: Wiring diagram]

[image: Schematic diagram]

[image: Photo of oscilloscope traces]

Comment: Be sure to explain exactly what is connected to each of the power rails on your breadboard. There are several wires that don't do anything useful -- the black wire at row 18, the black wire from 20 to 23, the red wire in row 28, and of course, the trimpot.

Comment: One of the electrolytic caps is in backwards, a bad thing.

Comment: Ah! I get it. Row 28 must be the signal input connection.

Comment: The bypass caps need to be next to the opamp, not have wire resistance and inductance in between

Comment: Does the circuit work properly if you apply a smaller input voltage? Have you measured the values of the two resistors to verify that they are as expected? Have you measured the voltages at the actual pins of the op amp to make sure they are as expected?

Comment: What is the input? what is it connected to? What impedance?

Comment: @BrianDrummond it is a scope rated at 50 Ohms

Comment: @KevinKruse I've updated the circuit to remove the wires that aren't doing anything. This used to have two op amps in series

Comment: @VoltageSpike I'll try placing them closer, but in my experience it is working fine to reduce the high frequency from the power supply. I've updated the schematic. Input impedance is from a function generator. Should be 50 ohms

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Yes, the gain is correct if I turn the input voltage down. I did measure the resistors, they're fine. I've looked at the input and output signals and power supply voltages. All match close enough to the settings

Comment: LT1222 is not a "unity gain stable" op amp and is only stable at gains greater than 10. Try changing resistors to increase the gain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the opamp's output current rating. I expect it's in the 20-30 mA region.

A 50 ohm load is much lower impedance than *most* opamps can reasonably drive.
Add about 1 kilohm in series with that 50 ohm scope input : that will give about 20:1 attenuation (at the scope) and I expect you'll get around the output voltage you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Instead of adding a resistor, the scope I'm using has a setting and I changed the impedance to 1 MOhm, and it stopped the clipping